# how come UDP server able recognize the UDP client?

Tags: networking, network-programming

An UDP client does not specify the source address while sending data-gram to UDP server.
So how come UDP server able recognize the UDP client and send back any data(response) that UDP client.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP client or server. The client/server concept is an application concept. UDP is a connectionless protocol that only sends without any expectation that what it sends will be received. TCP is a connection-oriented protocol that sets up a connection between peers. If you want clients and servers, you need to look at the application.

Comment: Assume if an application  sending data using UDP socket to a server application listening on UDP socket. Now if Server want to send reply any data to same client , is that possible?Because datagram received by server doest not have source IP address(client's) and source port number(client's).

Comment: That has nothing to do with UDP; that would be handled in the application. UDP is as bare-bones as you can get. If you want anything else, your application needs to handle it on UDP. UDP has no guarantees, but applications often add things like that when using UDP. That is handled by the application, and not UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you don't specify a source address doesn't mean that there isn't one. The source IP address is written by the operating system. It can therefore be read by the receiver of the packet.